# Save data to file before program will close not after

Tags: c, file, ansi-c

```
  if(RS_ile==1) 
  { 
     if(RS_buf == 1)   break; 
     if(RS_buf==49)
     printf("1\n");
     else
     {

     printf("%d\n", RS_buf); 
     fprintf (fp, "%d\n", RS_buf);
      fclose (fp);
     }  
  }
```

Everything work fine but all data was saved after I close my program. All I need is to put date to file while program is running not after closed.

Operating system Windows 8.1

Comment: What platform/OS are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `fflush(fp) ;` after your fprintf.

Comment: `fclose` automatically `fflush`es: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html

Comment: I was guessing he was doing fclose() at the end of the program, we're obviously missing a lot in the description.

Comment: Possibly, although the code snippet looks pretty self contained.